# How do I create my features

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-construction

I am working on the prediction of the behaviour of a new well in a map.
The data that I have is a map in a form of a grid and its properties (9 of them), and a set of wells with the position of each well in the map. And I have 4 outputs for each well.

Lets say i have 200 000 cells in my grid, it means that i have at least 9*200 000 features in my input, apart from the high dimension, these attributes are the same for all the wells, but at the same time they are important and I need to use them.

So my question is how can I use the map and its properties to choose my input features without being redundant for each well?

Answer (score 0):

Can I say this about your dataset? Say a well is a point on your map, so if each well has an x-axis and y-axis coordinates. So effectively I've converted your dataset into an 11-dimensional problem. Now let's talk prediction.

First, perform PCA on your dataset with the number of components = 1.Remember the dataset which you have to perform PCA is on all the data **but** the X-axis and Y-axis values Then plot your data set in a 3D scatter plot with the other two dimensions being X-axis and Y-axis and the third being the new Dimensionally reduced values done by PCA.

Look at the scatter plot if the following data follows any type of regression trend. Then use that type of regression to predict the values.